# PHP CLI echo/print missing text before array var....driving me mad

Tags: php, echo, command-line-interface

Running a script from the PHP CLI, I am echoing the following line:

```
echo "\r\nServer {$res['proxy']} | $response | $httpCode | OK";
```

However this is what is returned:

```
 | 4.003182888031 | 200 | OK
```

Its missing out the text before the $res['proxy'] var and the contents of the var (which should be an IP). Ironically though it is still doing the \r\n new lines!!

I've tried print instead of echo, `".$res['proxy']."` instead of curly braces, single quotes, changing the word 'server', removing the | pipes.

Whatever it is is making a fool out of me! What's going on :(

Comment: the word 'Server' along with the contents of $res['proxy'] which should be an IP address

Comment: I tried in my PC (XAMPP Windows), It's working here..how do you execute it?

Comment: The top of the script has: `#! /usr/bin/php
<?php` and I run the script with `./script.php`. I'm doing this all over SSH via Putty and have never seen this behavior in any of my other CLI scripts on this server

Comment: I don't think any problem in this. Just put a space after \n n try!

Comment: I tried \n at the end of the string. No joy. However, if i swap out `$res['proxy']` for `$res['id']` which is a plain integer, it echo's fine. So for some reason it does not like printing the IP addresses formatted like `1.2.3.4:8080`.

Comment: I've even just tried utf8_encode on the string and setting the putty output to UTF8. Nothing returned. This is really crazy :/

Comment: Is there any way you can execute script.php in browser & see the results?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38149/discussion-between-jenson-m-john-and-james-napier)